# Console code not working in service

Tags: c#, fax

This code was tested in a console application.  It would send a fax to the microsoft Fax Console and send an update query to the mysql database.  I have since transferred the code to a service application.  The mysql update is working and updating rows in my mysql table as "DONE", but the faxes are not being sent to the Fax Console.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using FAXCOMLib;
using FAXCOMEXLib;

namespace ProcessFaxes
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static Timer timer = new Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
        timer.Interval = 5000; // every 5 seconds
        timer.Enabled = true;
        //Console.ReadLine();
     }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    public static void Tick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=communications;Uid=myuser;password=mypass;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        MySqlConnection connupdate = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand commandupdate = connupdate.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE `faxstat` = 'Y' AND `fax` <> '' AND `faxpro` = 'PENDING'";
        //command.CommandText = "UPDATE blah blah";
        //conn.Open();
        //conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //conn.Close();

        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            connupdate.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["filepath"].ToString());
                SendFax(reader["id"].ToString(), reader["filepath"].ToString(), @"C:\FAXDOC\" + reader["filepath"].ToString(), reader["account"].ToString(), reader["fax"].ToString());
                string id = reader["id"].ToString();
                commandupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE outbox SET `faxpro` = 'DONE' WHERE `id` = '" + id + "'";
                commandupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        connupdate.Close();
    }

    public static void SendFax(string DocumentId, string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber)
    {
        if (FaxNumber != "")
        {
            try
            {
                FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass();
                faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName);


                FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);

                faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
                faxDoc.BillingCode = DocumentId;


                int Response = faxDoc.Send();


                faxServer.Disconnect();

            }
            catch (Exception Ex) { Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message); }
        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried replacing your Console.WriteLines with some form of logging to find out if your exception handling is catching something?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: FAXCOMLib. do you need to register that Lib on the server. perhaps the server you are porting this to does not have the same components that you have on your local.. if it works on your local machine..that's usually the dead give away..

Comment: I am writing the code and running the service on the same machine.  So everything is run locally.  I do not know how to replace my writelines with some other form of logging.

Comment: Possibly the FAXCOMLib needs to be ran with more access rights than a normal service.

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=VS.100).aspx for how to debug a windows service.

Comment: also I just noticed ..if you are doing a query every 5 seconds wouldn't you want to create a global connection object that stays open so that you don't have to make so many round trips.. you have several potential memory leaks "Garbage collection" in your code.. you are not disposing of created objects even though the GC will eventually clean it up.. I've seen issues like this in the past especially with Service apps.. also have you tried stopping and starting the service manually to see if it starts working properly..?

Comment: Look up log4net or nlog, they might be the quickest to introduce. I think that it's probably a permissions error as you're trying to install on the same machine as you have had it running from a console app on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tested c# code in console app / will not work in service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511779/tested-c-sharp-code-in-console-app-will-not-work-in-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible for us to tell given you've said the code works as a console application (so probably nothing in code is causing it not to work).

My instinct says it's a rights issue, as a windows service runs as a user with fewer rights than a normal user, debugging and encountering any exceptions raised should tell you what the issue is relatively quickly.

See the page on MSDN, [Debugging a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or research logging exceptions; at the moment you are writing to console, which you can't see as it's a service.

---

There have been a few comments on a few things you should tidy up, and following that advice would be a good idea, but shouldn't be related to why faxes aren't getting sent. As has been said, maybe reuse your connection, or wrap it in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement to ensure it gets disposed of as soon as it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I think giving the service rights allowed it to access the Windows Fax.  I learned how to log exceptions to the event log.  I will keep playing with it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code above if the fax server is a desktop application that runs under your user name or not. Either way, your Windows service will install under Local System account by default, and that account does not have access to YOUR user account, so it can't access anything that was installed just for your user name. You could try changing the service settings in the Windows service panel so your service runs under your user name. That will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

As it's working fine in a console app, there could be nothing wrong with your code. This might be something related to service dependencies. What is the FaxCOMLib? if that's another service running in your machine then you must register that as a dependency to your service.

You can register a service as follows (in command line):

```
sc config "NameOfYourService" depend= DependentServiceName
```

In your case the dependent service name may be the Fax Service.